# Inject script on every page in IE11/Windows RT 8.1?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, windows-rt

I want to automatically load `myScript.js` in every web page visited in IE11 on Windows RT 8.1. I've read that BHOs and toolbars are not possible on Windows RT. How else can I accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't you will have to do this at the proxy level. What you want can't be done with ie while it is in modern UI mode

Comment: I'm fine with using IE in desktop mode. Are there any other options?

Comment: Well you would have to find a IE RT extension which doesn't exist

Comment: So there are no other methods? :/